# Should I use StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, string, .net-3.5, stringbuilder, string-building

I have a code (C# .Net 3.5)  that looks like that:

```
string s1, s2;

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  s1 = "SomeString1"
  s2 = s1 + '.' + i
  SomeList.Add("Bla1" + s2);

  s1 = "SomeString2"
  s2 = s1 + '.' + i
  SomeList("Bla1" + s2);

  s1 = "SomeString3"
  s2 = s1 + '.' + i
  SomeList.Add("Bla1" + s2);
 .
 .
 .
 etc.....
}

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  s1 = "SomeString1"
  s2 = s1 + '.' + i
  SomeList.Add("Bla2" + s2);

  s1 = "SomeString2"
  s2 = s1 + '.' + i
  SomeList("Bla2" + s2);

  s1 = "SomeString3"
  s2 = s1 + '.' + i
  SomeList.Add("Bla2" + s2);
 .
 .
 .
 etc.....
}
.
.
.
etc...
```

n in not so big (around 5), and this pattern repeats for about 20 times.
This happens in the beginning of my program and I want the startup to be faster.
The question is: 
Is there a better way to do that (more efficient)? 
Should I use string builder instead of creating new strings over and over?
Will it help, or the "replace" actions will take as much time?

Thanks,
Yossi.

Comment: Why do you have the same code twice? (And it would really help if you'd write *real* code rather than pseudo-code missing semi-colons etc).

Comment: So is your question basically, '*How do I efficiently generate many strings with some pattern like `BlaXSomeStringY.Z`?*'

Comment: Your code is not very clear as it is clearly not your real code. But one question comes to mind anyway: Why do you create any strings at all?? Just add the expressions to the Lists! 


Other than that and as a general rule: Using `StringBuilder` will usually be the choice with the best performance, if there is a performance problem..

Comment: unless your n is huge you wont notice any significant performance difference. I would use whatever makes your code most readable.

Comment: If you want to know which of two things is faster then **write it both ways and try it**. Then you'll know.

Comment: No, StringBuilder will not improve this code, it is already optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
s1 = "SomeString1"
s2 = s1 + '.' + i
SomeList.Add("Bla2" + s2);
```

To:

```
SomeList.Add(string.Format("Bla2SomeString1.{0}", i));
```

That way you will reduce number of string allocations, concatenations, ...

Comment: Thanks Peter. Actually "somestringX" and "blaY" are defined in consts. So I cant write "SomestringXBlaY" Will it still improve the performence?